# PHP getting value from a dynamic select list

Tags: php

I've got a dynamic select list, which is generated from MySQL. I've got no problem listing them, but I cant seem to get it's value when I submit the form. Here's my script for the Select:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="make" name="make">
        <option value="">Make</option>
            <?php 
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $x = 1;
                While($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php $row[fmake];?>" <?php if($_POST['make'] == $row[fmake]) echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>><?php echo $row[fmake];?></option>
            <?php
            $x = $x + 1;
                }
            }?>
    </select>
</div>
```

And here's the script to get it's value:

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $make = $_POST['make'];
```

when I do an echo for $make, I don't get anything at all. What went wrong? All help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked source code of `select` element? what is shows?

Comment: Have you use `<form>` open and close tag

Comment: forgot to echo $row['fmake'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to echo $row['fmake'] and quotation marks mistake.

change this

```
<option value="<?php $row[fmake];?>" <?php if($_POST['make'] == $row[fmake]) echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>><?php echo $row[fmake];?></option>
```

by

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['fmake'];?>" <?php if($_POST['make'] == $row['fmake']) echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>><?php echo $row['fmake'];?></option>
```

Comment: My mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be `$row['fmake']`  instead of `$row[fmake]`

```
<option value="<?php $row['fmake'];?>" <?php if($_POST['make'] == $row['fmake']) echo 'selected="selected" '; ?>><?php echo $row['fmake'];?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe you're missing an echo.

```
value="<?php $row[fmake];?>"
```

Should be:

```
value="<?php echo $row[fmake];?>"
```